# Failing CORS on ajax requests to Neo4j

Tags: jquery, ajax, neo4j, cors

I'm experimenting with Backbone.js Models to access Neo4j content. I can't understand why the following communication is failing cross-origin checks:

First the OPTIONS request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:204 No Content
Request Headers
  Accept:*/*
  Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
  Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
  Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, content-type, accept
  Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
  Connection:keep-alive
  Host:localhost:7474
  Origin:http://localhost:3000
  Referer:http://localhost:3000/test/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
Response Headers
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, content-type, accept
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
  Allow:OPTIONS,POST
  Server:Jetty(6.1.25)
```

Then the POST request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
Request Headers
  Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
  Content-Type:application/json
  Origin:http://localhost:3000
  Referer:http://localhost:3000/test/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
Request Payload
  start n=node(0) match n-[:hasClass]->c where c.className=Collection return c
```

And I get console errors:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher 204 (No Content) jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

As far as I can tell, the request should be allowed, since the preflight request said that Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. Any suggestions? Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Chrome and I think [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743) might be related.

```
Ticket #67743: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * doesn't match localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

CORS fails on the legacy Cypher HTTP endpoint that is now deprecated.
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-cypher.html

The problem does not seem to occur on the new Transactional Cypher HTTP Endpoint.
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I dealt with cross-origin requests, but it could be that there is a missing header in some way. Not sure though. Note that the failure to comply with the request is generated by your browser, it could be worth checking what limitations your browser put on x-origin. For instance, many browsers do not allow it if you are using a file:// url.

Support for cross origin requests is not a documented feature of the Neo4j server, it's there for legacy reasons, and it will very likely be removed for security reasons (since there is no additional safety layer, your database could be hijacked if an attacker knows its URL).

It might be worth allowing it as an off-by-default setting though..